# IBM Cloud not creating Lite Plan Instance

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, instance

I do not have any instances in my resource list, but I still get the same message below when I try to create a new instance.

```
Service broker error: You can only have one instance of a Lite plan per service. To create a new instance, either delete your existing Lite plan instance or select a paid plan.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of instance are you trying to create? Double check if you don have any filters in your resource list active.

Answer (score 0):

Only one instance of a Lite plan per service is allowed. To create a new service instance, either delete your existing Lite plan service instance, or select a paid plan before continuing. You can also use your existing Lite plan service instance with the application how to solve this problem.